# How to save and retrieve text messages from UITextview

Tags: iphone, uitextview

```
 How to save and retrieve text which is in UITextView?
```

If anybody knows please help me. Give me some sample code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `text` property.

```
// set text
myTextView.text = @"my text";

// get text
NSString *txt = myTextView.text;
```

Comment: i am trying similar to sms application. In message we save some templates. that is what i am trying to do.

Comment: You can set and get text to UITextView by using text property. If that is not working then you have some problem in the implementation. Please edit your question to include some code. Otherwise it's almost impossible to guess what is wrong.

Comment: from this code its showing what is written myTextView.text = @"my text"; but i what. when the user type the text and press save then what the user wrote it should be display there.